# jQuery UI using ajax for autocomplete data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was wondering if I could use my own "webservice" that prints the content I need in the availabletags variable using the basic demo from jQuery ui api (without JSON etc) like this:

```
$(function() {

 var availabletags = $.ajax({ url: "myservice.jsp", async:     false }).responseText;  


$("#search").autocomplete({
  source: availabletags
});

});
```

myservice.jsp prints the content needed for autocomplete's source in to the file like this:

```
[
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
]
```

autocomplete works perfectly when I copy & paste above in the place of available tags after "source:" but when I try to do it via ajax it gives me 404 error.

is it possilbe to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this;

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
  source: "myservice.jsp"
});
```

Or

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "myservice.asp",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.value,
                            value: item.key
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And response will be in a format `key`, `value`

Comment: Both of those fix the error (thanks) but the jQuery autocomplete does not work with that. it sends the ajax call after two characters have been typed into the input field but autocomplete list does not open with possible options

Comment: @user1932076, sorry, I updated `data` with `item`. See my updated answer and apply it.

Comment: TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj
typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj ); Happens when the call is made after two chars typed

Comment: Could you please format your response as key value pair like `[{"key": "1", "value": "ActtionScript"}]` and use my updated asnwer

Answer (score 1):

```
<script> 
                   jQuery( document ).ready(function() {                       
                      jQuery('#search').keyup(function() {
                            //autocomplete
                        jQuery('#search').autocomplete({
                            source: 'your url',
                            autoFocus: true,

                            change: function (event, ui) {
                                if (ui.item == null || ui.item == undefined) {
                                    jQuery('#search').val('');
                                    jQuery('#search').attr('disabled', false);
                                } else {
                                    jQuery('#search').attr('disabled', false);
                                } }
                        });             

                    });
                    });
                   </script>
```

Comment: I seem to have the same problem with this as I had on the suggestions above. Ajax call works fine but it does not load them to autocomplete list appearing after two characters have been typed